# Разбить строку js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Есть строка:

```
'1-alexxosipov@asd.ru:dsfhsdasdqwe'
```

Как из нее с помощью js получить такой массив?

```
['1', 'alexxosipov@asd.ru', 'dsfhsdasdqwe']
```

Comment: а если в логине или пароле попадется `-`, то все ответы вам все сломают

Comment: @LexHobbit да, поэтому лучше исправлю символы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если строка всегда одного и того же шаблона, можно так:

```js
var str = '1-alexxosipov@asd.ru:dsfhsdasdqwe';
str = str.replace('-', ':');
var arr = str.split(':');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Да, всегда одного :) Спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let str = '1-alexxosipov@asd.ru:dsfhsdasdqwe';
let arr = str.split(/[-:]/);
console.log(arr);
```